# I forbad my iphone app to define my location. How can I allow?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, mkmapview

i am using iphone simulator. One time i chose "deny and do not ask me". But now i want using this functionality. How can I do this ?

my mac is 10.6.3 ; Do i need an update ? I didn't find  a check box "Disable Location Services"
Apple->System Preferences -> Security
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Apple->System Preferences -> Security In the general tab there is a check box "Disable Location Services" next to that there is a button to reset warnings. That should do it.

Comment: I didn't find a check box "Disable Location Services". Please , see the picture.

Comment: I am on 10.6.6 maybe it was added in an update since 10.6.3.   [link](http://i.imgur.com/ygVb1.png)

Answer (score 0):

With the iPhone Simulator open, click on the `iOS Simulator` menu then `Reset Contents and Settings`. This will erase all Apps from the simulator as well as reset it to the default settings.